# Print margins stuck in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos

I have print margins enabled in the text editor settings to show at 100 characters. However, it is stuck on showing at 120 characters. I have tried restarting Eclipse, enabling/disabling the setting, and setting it to multiple values. It does disappear if I disable the setting, but if it is enabled it is stuck showing at 120 characters. Any advice?

Comment: I have the same problem.  Have you found any solution?  Thanks!

Comment: @leeyuiwah Yes! I just posted the solution as an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It really helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java code style formatter settings actually override the `Print margin column` value in `General->Editors->Text Editors`. Go to `Java->Code Style->Formatter` and either select New or Edit. Under the `Line Wrapping` tab there is an option called `Maximum line width`, which is the value we want to change!